# Не закрывается блок уведомлений

Tags: дефект, уведомления

Если уведомление ведёт на тот же адрес, который открыт сейчас (в том числе тот же хэш), то при переходе по нему блок уведомлений не закрывается:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Судя по всему, это потому, что там ссылка с #, так что браузер просто переходит к якорю :) Но конечно баг.

Comment: @VladD, если бы был хотя бы другой якорь, блок бы закрылся - кто-то об этом подумал. Но именно при том же якоре закрытия не происходит. Возможно, кто-то по hashchange закрывает блок, а тут не change :)